# Clear different range of data in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is used as a template to fill in data. The data is cleared and the workbook is reused.
The workbook has multiple worksheets and the range that needs to be cleared is different in every worksheet.

Let's say I want to clear the data in the range A10:Y50, I put value "Start" in the cell Z10, as a starting point to clear data. "Start" is located in different cell in every worksheet.
The code is clearing data based on the "Start" located in the first worksheet and not independently for each worksheet.

```
Sub TestReset()
    
Dim sht As Worksheet
    
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name <> "Sheet1" And sht.Name <> "Sheet2" Then '
        Dim iRow As Long, iMax As Long
        
        iRow = Cells.Find(What:="start", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
        iMax = Cells(iRow, "A").End(xlDown).Row
    
        sht.Range("A" & iRow & ":AY" & iMax).ClearContents
    End If   
Next sht
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells.Find` and `Cells(iRow, "A")` look in the active worksheet.  You want `sht.Cells.Find` and `sht.Cells(iRow, "A")` to look at worksheet `sht`.  `sht.Range` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tony Dallimore mentioned in his comment you need to specify in what sheet you are looking for specific cells (if you dont specify it it assumes you are looking in ActiveSheet). So it is always best to specify with what sheet you work. It is good to use With statement for that. When you use With then it is enough to use only dot "."

```
Sub TestReset()
    
Dim sht As Worksheet
    
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    With sht

    If .Name <> "Sheet1" And .Name <> "Sheet2" Then '
        Dim iRow As Long, iMax As Long
        
        iRow = .Cells.Find(What:="start", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
        iMax = .Cells(iRow, "A").End(xlDown).Row
    
        .Range("A" & iRow & ":AY" & iMax).ClearContents
    End If   

    End with
Next sht
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's very useful! 
I actually have more than 100 sheets in workbook so I would prefer to specify which sheets to exclude rathen to indicate the sheets that I want to clear content in. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: I would list their name in cells in specific sheet, for example Settings. For example A1 = "Sheet1", A2 = "Sheet2" etc. And then i would use Find in that range and if it is found then i would skip it... I can add another answer with simple code...

Comment: I would really appreciate it, as I am very new in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Also use Dim iRow as Long before for each loop... But here is added example of how you can manage sheets to skip (Create sheet "Setup" and in cell A1 add name to skip, for example Sheet1, in cell A2 add Sheet2 and it should do the trick.

```
Sub WorkInUnSpecifiedSheets()


    Dim xRng As Range
    'sheet "Setup" must exist and Range A1 contains name of sheet to skip, current region might not work on some PCs. But it is simple
    Set xRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'you can also use another method to specify range... Named ranges for example or using last row and last column...
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 'i would recommend using ThisWorkbook or Workbook variable instead of Active
    
        If xRng.Find(What:=sht.Name, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then
              
              'your code to work in unspecified sheets
              
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub
```